# Selecting Particular Column in a Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, datagridview

I have a gridview in which there are multiple records i am showing. On a page load event, i am retrieving data from database and populate the gridview. I have another column for edit and delete which are Imagebuttons. Now i want when a user click on edit button, then on the bases of Id (of that row upon a user clicked),he/she redirects to another webform with the selected Id and then that person records loads from database and populate the corresponding textboxes. I am not updating records within Gridview.
Here is the image for clear understandings
[image]

Here is my .aspx code

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgvEmployeesInformation" runat="server" CssClass=" table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="dgvEmployeesInformation_RowCommand">
                <%--1st Column--%>
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="ID" DataField="Id" ShowHeader="false" Visible="false" ControlStyle-BackColor="#0066ff"/>
                    <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="Name" DataField="Name"/>
                    <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="Employee No" DataField="EmployeeNo"/>
                    <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="Father Name" DataField="FatherName"/>
                    <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="CNIC" DataField="CNIC"/>
                    <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="Contact No" DataField="ContactNo"/>
                    <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="City" DataField="City"/>
                    <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="Post" DataField="RecommendedPost"/>
                    <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="Status" DataField="Status"/>
                    <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="Degree Status" DataField="DegreeStatus"/>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/Images/edit.png" CommandName="Edit" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' ToolTip="Edit" Width="20px" Height="20px" runat="server"/>
                            <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/Images/delete.png" CommandName="Delete" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' ToolTip="Delete" Width="20px" Height="20px" runat="server"/>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Here is .aspx.cs Code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            dgvEmployeesInformation.DataSource = GetData();
            dgvEmployeesInformation.DataBind();
        }
    }

    private DataSet GetData()
    {
        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Base.GetConnection))
        {

            SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("spSelectEmployeeSpecificRecord", con);
            ad.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            ad.Fill(DS);
        }
        return DS;
    }
protected void dgvEmployeesInformation_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName.Equals("Edit"))
        {

        }
    }
```

I have no idea how to get ID of the selected row and send it to another page. Please Help

Comment: Which column you want/already set as ID? I think you can use `SelectedRow` and `DataKeyNames` for particular column.

Answer (score 1):

the `e.CommandArgument` contains the index you have click on it.
and the `dgvEmployeesInformation.SelectedValue` contains the Id that you have set on  `DataKeyNames`.

Set on `DataKeyNames` the database field you have as `id` - in your case `DataKeyNames="EmployeeNo"` and the code can be as

```
protected void dgvEmployeesInformation_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName.Equals("Edit"))
    {
        int SelectedIndex;
        if (int.TryParse(e.CommandArgument.ToString(), out SelectedIndex))
        {
            // make it selected after the click
            dgvEmployeesInformation.SelectedIndex = SelectedIndex;

            // now the SelectedValue contains the id
            Edit(dgvEmployeesInformation.SelectedValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
void yourGridView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
// If multiple buttons are used in a GridView control, use the
// CommandName property to determine which button was clicked.
if(e.CommandName=="Edit")
{
// Convert the row index stored in the CommandArgument
// property to an Integer.
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

// Retrieve the row that contains the button clicked 
// by the user from the Rows collection.
GridViewRow row = ContactsGridView.Rows[index];
var yourID = row.Cells[0].Text;
//....
}
}
```

[Grid view learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onrowcommand?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: I have an ImageButton, i want to get the Id which hidden in a gridview, when a user click on imageButton, then he/she redirected to another webform, with the Id of that Row. `ContactsGridView` gets me an error, `Does not exist in the current context`

Comment: change it with your grid view name (sorry i didn't use your variable names)

Comment: Its not working because when i type cast it with my ImageButton, it throws error, 
`if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
                {
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                GridViewRow row = dgvEmployeesInformation.Rows[Index];
                var UserId= row.Cells[0].Text;
                Response.Redirect("~/AddEmployeeBasic1.aspx?Id=" + ((ImageButton)sender).ToString());
                 }      `

Comment: why you put this : Response.Redirect("~/AddEmployeeBasic1.aspx?Id=" + ((ImageButton)sender).ToString()); I think you should use the UserId instead of ((ImageButton)sender).ToString())... somthing like that Response.Redirect("~/AddEmployeeBasic1.aspx?Id=" +  UserId)  ;

Comment: For that, i have to get the Id, but i am not able to get the Id of the selected row. How to select the id? After getting the Id, then i can redirect.